# How to get the address of BLE device which I am reading for RSSI?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I have implement for connecting to multiple **`BLE device`** by using multiple **`BluetoothGatt parameter`** in **`Android`**.

I use **`mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();`** to read the **RSSI** , and receive the RSSI value via `BroadcastReceiver` like the following code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_RSSI.equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                    int rssi = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_RSSI, 0);
                    Log.i(TAG, "mGattreceiver   BroadcastReceiver---rssi = " + rssi);
                }
            }
        };
```

I can get the **RSSI** via above code , and I also see the log like the following

```
11-07 17:09:29.595: D/BluetoothGatt(16612): onReadRemoteRssi() - Device=20:73:20:00:6C:C5 rssi=-56 status=0
```

But if there has multiple **`BLE device`** , I will get multiple **`RSSI`** value but didn't has **`BLE address`** in **`BroadcastReceiver`**

How to get the **`address of BLE device`** which I am reading for **RSSI** ?

Can I get the **`address`** in **`BroadcastReceiver`**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the snippet on [this link](http://answer.techwikihow.com/1308102/android-update-bluetooth-rssi-second.html)

Answer (score 2):

`BluetoothDevice` has a method called `getAddress()` which returns the MAC address of the device.

If you don't have it handy, you can get an instance of `BluetoothDevice` using `BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);`